# How do you use Timers in C# to wait for a certain amount of time before doing something?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I was told that as opposed to using `Thread.Sleep(int)` to cause the program to wait for a certain amount of time before proceeding, I should use Timers.

I was wondering how this should be done? Could someone give me a short example?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at the first hit on msdn? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Create a timer with

```
Timer _timer = new Timer();
```

Initialize the timer with

```
_timer.Interval = 5000; // Time in milliseconds.
_timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
_timer.Start();
```

The timer tick event handler

```
void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do the timed work here
}
```

You can stop the timer with

```
_timer.Stop();
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can add the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`-component to a `Form` (to its component tray to be precise). This has the advantage that you can set its properties and the Tick-event from the properties window.

Check also for the documentation of the other timers: [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), [System.Web.UI.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) and [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). Abhishek Sur has written a nice comparision [here](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/all-about-net-timers-comparison.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
 myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

 // Sets the timer interval to 5 seconds.

myTimer.Interval = 5000;

myTimer.Start();
```

This will cause the TimeEventProcessor to be executed in 5s without blocking the current thread.